# Use ContextReplacementPlugin for dynamically setting the resource path in require.context

Tags: webpack, next.js

I want to import the posts from two folders, 'NL' and 'JP'. And use a dynamically set folder for that.

When I write the folder include statically it works:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import importAllMarkdown from '../importAllMarkdown';
import { Data, PostBlog } from '../shared.types';

type countryCode = 'NL' | 'JP';

function usePosts(countryCode: countryCode): Data<PostBlog>[] | null {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState<Data<PostBlog>[] | null>(null);

  useEffect(() => {

    // this codeblock for each country :(
    if (countryCode === 'NL') {
      const importedPosts: Data<PostBlog>[] = 
        importAllMarkdown(require.context('../posts/NL', true, /\.md$/));

      setPosts(importedPosts);
    }

    if (countryCode === 'JP') {
      const importedPosts: Data<PostBlog>[] =
        importAllMarkdown(require.context('../posts/JP', true, /\.md$/));

      setPosts(importedPosts);
    }
  }, [countryCode, setPosts]);

  return posts;
}

export default usePosts;
```

As you can see in this example, for each country you have to add an entire block to import the files in that folder.

When you'd dynamically set the folder:

```
const folderPath = `../posts/${countryCode}`;
const importedPosts: Data<PostBlog>[] = 
  importAllMarkdown(require.context(folderPath, true, /\.md$/));
```

..it gives the error: `TypeError: __webpack_require__(...).context is not a function`.

Now from this [Github thread](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/4772) it seems that [ContextReplacementPlugin](http://ContextReplacementPlugin) can be used for dynamically setting the folder.

> *"An alternative is to use require(variable) and use the ContextReplacementPlugin to provide the "staticness" via config. In this case you need to specify all possible values of variable in the arguments of the plugin (or crawl a directory)."*

So what I'm trying:

**./next.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  webpack(config, { webpack }) {
    config.plugins.push(new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
      /^\..\/posts/,
      /NL|JP/,
    ));
    return config;
  },
};
```

This still produces the error: `TypeError: __webpack_require__(...).context is not a function`.

What is going wrong?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: Kinda. Added an answer. Hope this helps your issue too.

Comment: Thanks, I did end up doing something similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it isn't possible to use variables as arguments in `require.context`. The error message is a bit unclear for this issue. But [the documentation](https://webpack.js.org/guides/dependency-management/#context-module-api) states: **"The arguments passed to require.context must be literals!"**.

This can be solved by querying the whole folder and then filter the results based on the ones you would need.

In the example above it would be:

```
// needed to separate the posts based on the country
const byCountry = (post: Data<PostBlog>, countryCode: countryCode): boolean => post.slug.split('/')[1] === countryCode;

function usePosts(countryCode: countryCode): Data<PostBlog>[] | null {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState<Data<PostBlog>[] | null>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const importedPosts: Data<PostBlog>[] = importAllMarkdown(require.context('../posts', true, /\.md$/));
    const onlyCurrentCountryPosts = importedPosts.filter((post) => byCountry(post, countryCode));
    const sortedCurrentCountryPosts = onlyCurrentCountryPosts.sort(byDate).reverse();

    setPosts(sortedCurrentCountryPosts);
  }, [countryCode, setPosts]);

  return posts;
}

export default usePosts;
```

However that is a bit inefficiënt. For each usePosts call it would query for all the posts and then return a subsection.